# Memory leak with gunicorn gevent stream responses and zeromq

Tags: wsgi, zeromq, gevent, gunicorn, pyzmq

I'm serving an MJPEG streaming response from gunicorn with gevent workers.  Everything works fine but when the connection is terminated by the client it appears that the zeromq subscriber isn't GC'd and just keeps on accepting image data.

Here is the memory usage for gunicorn:

[image: memory leak]

Here is the source code for the wsgi app:

```
from gevent_zeromq import zmq


context = zmq.Context()


def app(environ, start_response):
    if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/':
        subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        subscriber.connect("ipc:///tmp/camera")
        subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
        boundary = "--ipcamera"

        status = '200 OK'
        headers = [('Content-type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary={}'.format(boundary))]
        start_response(status, headers)

        def get_frames():
            while True:
                yield subscriber.recv()

        return get_frames()

    status = '404 NOT FOUND'
    headers = []
    start_response(status, headers)
    return status
```

I'm running gunicorn with --max-requests 5 to help but obviously isn't a solution.  I don't even know where to begin to hunt down the culprit :/

Comment: What are you doing to destroy the socket if the connection is terminated?

Comment: Nothing.  I was assuming everything would get GC'd when the connection is terminated.  Is there some way that I can act on the event the connection is terminated?  The wsgiref in the std lib raises a broken pipe exception, should I try catching that?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution; catch the exception, then do a `close()` and `destroySocket()`. But hold on a sec, is `subscriber` an instance variable? According to the code above, it is; sharing sockets between concurrent requests wont work. Is `app()` called simultaneously from different threads?

Comment: There are no instance variables.  app() is a wsgi app, which is just a callable that accepts environ and start_response for each request and returns a iterator of the response body.  The subscriber isn't shared between requests.  As for how app is called, I'm not sure since that is done by gunicorn but I'm using gevent workers so I assume it is using greenlets.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this memory leak by removing gevent_zeromq and just using pyzmq==13.1.0 which includes gevent support.